# Is there a way to detect power state change from the command line?

Tags: launchd, power

I would like to disable some power hungry services once I disconnect the power cord.  Was thinking of creating a launchd agent that can monitor a file and run a script.

If there are other ways of doing this without purchasing a separate app, that would be OK as well.  Although, preferred way would be to do it with existing macOS commands.

Comment: Which "power hungry services"? Perhaps the problem is "why are these services using a lot of power, and is there a way to fix it?"

Comment: A cloud backup service that should really be doing its job when it is on AC power rather than when on battery.

Answer (score 1):

To get notifications about power source changes, see [IOPowerSources.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-1050.20.2/ps.subproj/IOPowerSources.h.auto.html) and the `kIOPSNotifyPowerSource` notification:

> ### kIOPSNotifyPowerSource
>
> C-string key for a notification of changes to the active power source.
>
> Use this notification to discover when the active power source changes from AC power (unlimited/wall power),
> to Battery Power or UPS Power (limited power). IOKit will not deliver this notification when a battery's
> time remaining changes, only when the active power source changes. This makes it a more effiicent
> choice for clients only interested in differentiating AC vs Battery.

## Third Party: Power Manager

Power Manager can [run a script when switching to battery power](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-07-12-how-to-run-a-command-when-switching-to-battery-power/). Use the built-in task **Run a script on switch to battery** to create the event:

[image: Power Manager on macOS]

Power Manager is a commercial product which I work on. Feel free to get in touch and ask technical questions about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `system_profiler` to get this info.

```
% system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -i “current power source” -B10
```

You will get the current power source and the relevant details.  For example, on my iMac, I get the following:

```
AC Power:
      System Sleep Timer (Minutes): 45
      Disk Sleep Timer (Minutes): 10
      Display Sleep Timer (Minutes): 10
      Sleep on Power Button: Yes
      Automatic Restart on Power Loss: No
      Wake on LAN: Yes
      AutoPowerOff Delay: 259200
      AutoPowerOff Enabled: 1
      Current Power Source: Yes.      <- This tells you this is the current power source
      DarkWakeBackgroundTasks: 0
      Display Sleep Uses Dim: Yes
      Hibernate Mode: 0
      High Standby Delay: 86400
      PrioritizeNetworkReachabilityOverSleep: 0
      Standby Battery Threshold: 50
      Standby Delay: 86400
      Standby Enabled: 1
```

Comment: Wondering if there is a way to detect it when it happens, i.e., via a call-back or monitoring a file change.  I believe in older macOS versions, a file would change when the power state changed.

Comment: You would need a process continually running to detect this.